# Android retrofit 2, Slim запрос

Tags: android, retrofit, slim

у меня имеется код, который загружает все данные о городах. Как передавать строку, чтобы искать города, содержащих эту строку? Какой запрос нужен GET или POST?

Интерфейс

```
public interface APIService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("register")
     Call<Result> createUser(
            @Field("login") String login,
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("password") String password,
            @Field("phone") String phone,
            @Field("gender") String gender
    );

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("login")
    Call<Result> userLogin(
            @Field("login") String login,
            @Field("password") String password
    );


    @GET("cities")
Call<Cities> getCities(@Query("query")String query);

    @GET("shops")
    Call<Shops> getShops();
}
```

Код

```
public void LoadData(String query){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

    Call<Cities> call = service.getCities(query);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Cities>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Cities> call, Response<Cities> response) {

            adapter = new CityAdapter(response.body().getCities(),getActivity());
            recyclerViewCity.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Cities> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

PHP. Использую SLIM:

```
$app->get('/cities', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('query'))){
        $requestData = $request->getParsedBody();
        $query = $requestData['query'];
        $db = new DbOperation();
        $cities = $db->getAllCities($query);
        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode(array("cities" => $cities)));
    }

});

....

function getAllCities($query){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id, region, autonom, area, city, city_2 FROM locality WHERE ((region LIKE ? and autonom is null and area is null and city is null and city_2 is null) or (city LIKE ? and city_2 is null) or(city_2 LIKE ?))");
        $stmt-> bind_param("sss", $query, $query, $query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $region, $autonom, $area, $city, $city_2);
        $cities = array();
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            $temp = array();
            $temp['id'] = $id;
            $temp['region'] = $region;
            $temp['autonom'] = $autonom;
            $temp['area'] = $area;            
            $temp['city'] = $city;
            $temp['city_2'] = $city_2;
            array_push($cities, $temp);
        }
        return $cities;
    }
```

Возвращается пустая строка, хотя если я выполню SQL-запрос  в бд, он вернет значение.

В чем ошибка? Может я неправильно передаю строку запроса? или ошибка в Серверной части?

В PostMan получается GET-Запрос : `http://localhost/Retrofit/public/cities?query="Москва"` и он возвращает `{"cities":[]}`.

Попробовал в `$app->get('/cities',` вставить значение по умолчанию.
В postman выдал GET-запрос: `http://localhost/Retrofit/public/cities`

Метод после изменений:

```
$app->get('/cities', function (Request $request, Response   $response) {

        $requestData = $request->getParsedBody();

        $query = 'Москва';
        $db = new DbOperation();
        $cities = $db->getAllCities($query);
        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode(array("cities" => $cities)));

});
```

Выдало результат:

```
{"cities":[{"id":12865,"region":"\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430","autonom":null,"area":null,"city":null,"city_2":null}]}
```

Значит ошибка, либо в приеме переменной, либо в передаче. Помогите найти ошибку

Comment: Это надо смотреть в API - есть ли там такая возможность. Если - да там и будет написано какой запрос отправить. Очевидно, что это будет GET. В приведённом же вами коде такой возможности нет совсем. Можно лишь вручную в полученной информации искать совпадения по строкам.

Comment: если вы про серверную часть api, то там я добавлю, как из приложения отправить строку?

Comment: Вам нужно будет добавить параметр в метод для GET запроса и пометить его аннотацией `@Query`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб посмотрите измененный код. Я правильно передал параметр? И по какому url принимать параметры в back end

Comment: Передаёте правильно. Ошибка где-то в приеме. Проверьте что получаете на сервере. Может не так параметр вытаскиваете или не в той кодировке

Comment: Хорошо, тогда лучше создам отдельный вопрос